# Making a Stack of arrays and 2d arrays of vectors

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to use the STL stack in order to save my variables. I have two variables declared as vector array[8][8] and an int array[8][8]. How would I declare the stack?
Would it be something like

```
stack<vector<int>> array
stack<int>array// not really sure how to use stacks at this point.
```

Edit: This is what I want to do:

```
class example
{
    private:
    vector<int> cells[8][8]//2d array of vectors, one vector for each of the 64 cells
    int table[8][8]; //table of 64 elements
    //here is what I want to implement
    stack<int,vector<int>> cells_stack;// a stack of vectors so that I can backtrack on the vectors if inputs on the table are incorrect
    stack<int> table_stack;//stack of array so that I can backtrack;
};
```

Comment: Example code can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/stack/).

Comment: I'm still confused, because that only applies to one vector. 
    `vector<int> table[8][8]`
    `int array[9][9]`
so would the stack of the 2d array be `stack<int>` and the vectors would be `stack<vector<int>>`? Not having to list the size of the arrays that is stored in the stack?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to do.  In your question you declare two `stack` variables: one of them a `stack` of type `vector` and the other a `stack` of type `int`.  Do you want both of these to be stored on a single `stack`?  Perhaps it might be best for you to write the code as best you can and add it to your question so we have a starting point we can discuss.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited the question to better identify my question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to store the contents of `cells` and `table` on stacks.  If that is correct, then what you want to do is declare your stacks exactly the same as the objects you want to store.  Since `cells` is an 8x8 array of type `vector<int>` then that's what `cells_stack` should contain.  For example:

```
stack<vector<int>[8][8]> cells_stack;
```

The same goes for `table_stack`, which should contain 8x8 arrays of type `int`:

```
stack<int[8][8]> table_stack;
```

Comment: Thanks Carey, that's exactly what I was looking for! I would give you rep but I myself don't have 15 rep yet, sorry

Comment: I just tired doing stack<int[8][8]> and the vector stack, it gives me a really long error message and i only declared it in my class.

Comment: @user3251195 Show the error and tell us what compiler you are using.

Comment: I'm not sure which version of g++ i'm using, but the error is like in instantiation of 'void std::_construct(...)'. The last line is requrest for member '~std:;vector<int>[8][8]' in `*_pointer`, which is of non-class type `std:;vector<int>[8]8[]`. I also included <stack>

Comment: Could you copy and paste the actual error message and put it in quotes or something?  I can't tell what you're saying and what's error message.